# Custom Sharepoint Web Part - resetting property to initially set value

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, search, web-parts

I have been writing a pretty basic search web part to return items from a specific list.

My web part is working fine until I change some of the custom property fields. While debugging I have found that my web part seems to be running twice, although I know their is only once instance on the page (Have checked using [http://mysite?Content=1])

One run of the web part is using the changed properties and one uses the initial property which is causing it to crash. Can anyone suggest a reason for why this would occur and how to avoid it.

Any help is greatly appreciated - Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you get hit for your code twice , so it definitely means that that there are two webparts present in the page, few options I suggest are

1. Create a new page and test this
2. Check for Closed webPart, Closed webparts dont show in UI but execution and event happens
3. [Refer This link](http://www.raregrooverider.com/post/2008/02/25/Closed-versus-Deleted-Web-Parts-in-SharePoint.aspx) to get to know the difference.
4. You need to use contents=1 not just content=1 as you mentioned in question

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that did not resolve my issue. For some reason I have also found that the SET method for only 1 of my custom web part properties is running on every page load and none of the others are. This set code calls a function,which is somehow using the initial default value that one of my other properties was set to - causing the error.